# Using VB DLL in .NET 3.5 Windows application ERROR

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, vb6, assemblies

I have a Visual Basic DLL, I used it in a Windows User Control Application. It works fine, **but** when I HOST this Windows User Control in another Windows Forms application, it gives me the following error.

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {66DF4F1A-E3E2-43D3-92BC-D56E9DDCB8AC} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a005b.

When I run the User Control it works fine with me, ONLY when I host it in another Windows application this error occurs.

- I'm using Visual Studio 2008 & Windows Server 2003
- when I add the User Control, the DLL path is "C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\HMS_WF4\HMS_WF4\obj\Release\Interop.DLLNAME.dll"

Notes. it's in Release, but when I compile the application it puts the output in the `Debug` folder. Even if I select the `Release` folder for debugging and compilation, when the application is run, it searches for the DLL in the `Release` folder, but it's in the `Debug` folder.

Comment: when i added the VB6 assembly in WINDOWS  USER CONTROL , it's name preceded by "Interop" then 
"NAME.DLL" automatically , but when i add it to the windows application that hosted USER CONTROL , it's name still "NAME.DLL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it....

When I host the User Control in a Windows Forms application, it initialize objects from the User Control objects in `Form1.Designer.vb`.  Like  `Me.FrmTransactions31.TransHdr = CTransHdrClass2`.

I just replaced `CTransHdrClass2`  with `Nothing`

Thanks for all.